# Divide Variable in HTML Style Tag

Tags: html, css, variables, styles, division

I would like to divide the variable `$depth` by 2 in a HTML style tag, but it returns the error:

```
unknown token 2 in term
```

Different trials containing parentheses failed too.

Here's my code:

```
<xsl:variable name="depth" select="count(ancestor::*)"/>        
<table border="1" style="margin-left: {$depth/2}px;">
```

Multiplying `{$depth*2}` or adding `{$depth+2`} is no problem.
Substracting `{$depth-2}` fails with an out of range error. The variable `$depth` starts at value 5 and rises by 2 every loop.

Is there a way to 'escape' the operation or the number, or am I completely wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: if `{$depth*2}` is working try `{$depth*0.5}` which is the same as `{$depth/2}`

Comment: OMG. You're Right. Sometimes the answer is so easy. :-)